# KSOAP fault exception

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using SOAP service in my application.In that i am receiving the error message

```
 SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 301). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='authentication',
```

My SOAP request structure is:

```
 <authentication>
    <LoginID>string</LoginID>
    <Password>string</Password>
  </authentication>
  <Id>int</Id>
  <Str>string</Str>
```

My code is:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                PropertyInfo usrid =new PropertyInfo();
            usrid.setName("LoginID");
            usrid.setValue(userid);
            usrid.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(usrid);        

//          
            PropertyInfo pass =new PropertyInfo();
            pass.setName("Password");
            pass.setValue(password);
            pass.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pass);

                PropertyInfo rote =new PropertyInfo();
            rote.setName("Id");
            rote.setValue(4114616);
            rote.setType(int.class);
            request.addProperty(rote);
//          
            PropertyInfo dte =new PropertyInfo();
            dte.setName("Str");
            dte.setValue(date);
            dte.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(dte);



 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);              
//              SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                System.out.println("subbu");
                Object response=(Object)envelope.getResponse();---->I think i am getting error here.
```

Can anybody please help what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following links:

- http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks
- http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

`authentication` is a complex object but you have added all the properties in a row. Try something like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

SoapObject authenticate = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "authenticate");
authenticate.addProperty("LoginID", "login");
authenticate.addProperty("Password", "password");

request.addSoapObject(authenticate);
request.addProperty("Id", "123");
request.addProperty("Str", "string");
```

Comment: First of all, you didn't post your code, so it is hard to say "_what have you did wrong_".

Comment: StenaviN  ,i tried your code but in the line request.addSoapObject(authenticate);
in my code its not supporting addSoapObject.After request. it shows nothing relates to addSoapObject..

Comment: Thanks to all .its solved..Actually the problem is the version of SOAP jar file.Previously i used 2.5.2 now i am using 2.6.0.